# JavaScript function test fail

Tags: javascript, function

I seem to not be to pass all the tests:

```
function profileActivation(profile, reason) {
  if (reason === "confirm status manually") {
    profile.active = true;
  }

  if (profile.active) {
    if (profile.reason) {
      return "confirm status manually";
    } else {
      delete profile.reason;
      return profile;
    }
  } else {
    if (!profile.reason) {
      return "confirm status manually";
    } else {
      profile.active = true;
      return profile;
    }
  }
}

//  profileActivation takes two arguments, profile and reason, which are an object and a string respectively
//  The reason arg is only used -and therefore required- to deactivate profiles, not to activate them
//  The profile arg has an `active` property holding a Boolean value
//    * If profile is active, profileActivation deactivates it and writes a `reason` prop holding the reason
//    * If profile is inactive, profileActivation activates it and deletes the `reason` prop from the object
//    * In both cases the updated profile object is returned
//  Edge cases:
//    * If the profile is inactive but its `reason` prop is **missing**, return the string "confirm status manually"
//    * If the profile is active but it has a `reason` prop, return the string "confirm status manually"
//    * If the profile is **missing** an `active` prop, return the string "impossible to ascertain status"
//  HINT: to confirm the existence of a prop, check that its value is not undefined
```

Only passing 3 and four

Comment: what does `only passing 3 and four` mean? What is `3`? What is `four`? Why is one a number and the other a word? Why is that block of text so hard to read?

Comment: What about the edge case where an active profile is being deactivated and reason argument is undefined or not a string?

Comment: well i guess i need to go back a Module and reacces what ive learned. i dont know why it has to be difficult.

Comment: I take it the answer I posted doesn't help

Comment: $ echo $PATH
/c/Users/Catfishfishcat/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/Catfishfishcat/bin:/c/Python311/Scripts:/c/Python311:/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/TXE Components/iCLS:/c/Program Files/Intel/TXE Components/iCLS:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDOWS:/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH:/c/Program Files/Intel/TXE Components/DAL:/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/TXE Components/DAL:/c/Program Files/Intel/TXE Components/IPT:/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/TXE

Comment: im pretty sure i jacked up some settings somewhere. cause im having a real hard time utilizing VS Code and Git...

Comment: no idea what your PATH or git has to do with this question!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are using the `reason` argument in the first line of the function - the description of the function never mentions using the reason to activate a profile!

Your code also never returns `"impossible to ascertain status"`, so it's like you completely ignored that edge case

The way I would do it is to handle the edge cases first, and then handle activation/de-activation.

Anyway, here's the code I came up with

```js
function profileActivation(profile, reason) {
    // handle edge cases
    // edge case 1 and 2
    if (profile.active === (profile.reason !== undefined)) {
        return "confirm status manually";
    }
    // edge case 3
    if (profile.active === undefined) {
        return "impossible to ascertain status";
    }
    // toggle activation
    profile.active = !profile.active;
    // add/remove reason as required
    if (!profile.active) {
        profile.reason = reason;
    } else {
        delete profile.reason;
    }
    return profile;
}
console.log('Test 1', profileActivation({}));
console.log('Test 2', profileActivation({"active":true,"reason":""}));
console.log('Test 5', profileActivation({"active":true},"because"));
console.log('Test 6', profileActivation({"active":false,"reason":"because"}));
```

Seems to do what is expected

Edit: removed OP's code since it was confusing OP

Comment: it still is not passing all test.

Comment: Test 1 fails:
 profileActivation({})
 should return "impossible to ascertain status"
 but returns "confirm status manually"
Test 2 fails:
 profileActivation({"active":true,"reason":""})
 should return "confirm status manually"
 but returns {"active":true}
index.html:262
 Test 5 fails:
 profileActivation({"active":true},"because")
 should return {"active":false,"reason":"because") but returns {"active":true}Test 6 fails:
        profileActivation({"active":false,"reason":"because"})
         should return {"active":true}
         but returns {"active":true,"reason":"because"}

Comment: @WilliamJohnson - I just added those Test cases that fail, yet they produce the expected output - perhaps you didn't actually use my code and used your code instead

Comment: i try not to copy and paste. ill double check.

Comment: well, the failure is exactly like your original code, so, it seems you have done nothing :p

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76597473/22161354

Comment: what about it? it's nothing like the code I posted, it's worse than your original @WilliamJohnson